# translate rails namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, namespaces, routes

lets say i have the following resource

```
map.namespace :admin do |a|
  a.resources :users
end
```

to access the users index action I would have to type

```
/admin/users
```

How can I translate this route to different languages?

```
map.namespace :admin do |a|
  a.resources :users, :as => ipsum
end
```

would result in

```
/admin/ipsum
```

How can i change e.g. the admin part to "lorem" so that my route would look like

```
/lorem/ipsum
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be against using a plugin for this?

http://github.com/raul/translate_routes